Creative usage of поилка
If I used поилка in the context of a conversation about bars …

would it be understood, that I am using this word to refer to a bar? Especially, would it be understood such, that I deem the so described bar as one that is shabby and serves low quality drinks?
or would it just sound wrong/weird?

Note: I am asking this question in the pursuit of developing a better sense for the language, which, in my opinion, includes creative usage of language. I couldn‘t find any dictionary entries or examples that support such usage, but due to it being related to words like пойло and поить, I assume it could work to use поилка in such a derogatory sense.

The correct Russian term is "наливайка".

@alamar that's also a z-gen thing. But funny.

Gen-X is рюмочная, but it's too post-modern now when a decent venue may be called that.

Поилка would not be idiomatic or readily understood.
The word поильня can sometimes, quite rarely, be used in the sense you're mentioning:


Хорошая такая поильня, завсегдатай тут я. И менять свои привычки не собираюсь. (from an online review of a bar)
Очень мне понравился этот новый удар по анкоголизму. Значится, вот это вот новое распоряжение, по которому уже третья, кажется, часть варшавских пивных в поильню минеральных вод превращается.
(Of bars and churches) Собиральни бабла с граждан. И там, и там. Каждая создаёт свою атмосферу, но даёт иллюзию ухода от действительности. Две коммерческие структуры, но одна (поильня) говорит об этом прямо, а вторая рассказывает о чём угодно, отрицая коммерческую составляющую, но жаждет именно денег от приходящие или посещающих. И по смыслу особых отличий нет.


The suffix -н- in combination with the ending -я- is productive in this sense: едальня, харчевня, изба-читальня "rural club", дрочильня "erotic massage parlor" etc.
Note though that "productive" means that it has a potential to produce idiomatic words in a certain sense, but is not guaranteed to do that. You can't just slap this suffix to any old word and hope it will result in something actually being used in the language.

In my expirience, дрочильня while it could mean THAT, in fact it means a place where people do a pointless work. Compare that to some exuisite British speech examples like "stop playing with yourselves, move your asses!", a comparable Russian analog is "Хватит тут дрочить, и погнали"

Most likely it would be understood from a context, but it will sound weird. Поилка is a drinking “device” that you would put into a hamster or bird cage, or maybe a water supply for the farm animals.

It's an OK name for a trendy bar. I know one with similar naming. But that's not conductive to the declared writer intent.

I suppose, you had translated "watering hole" literally? That's not how colliquial speech translation works. Поилка for us is either a through for animals to drink water from or some device, a water dispenser. Sometimes cooler stands or drinking fountains are called that.
When in joking or sarcastic mood today, we can use one of outdated terms like питейная (a old-timey general term for place where alcoholic drinks are served). Поильня is a neologism, likely created by "nadmozg"* translotors  when they had to deal with "watering hole". A Z-gen might use that, I never saw millenials or someone before that using the term.
In historic cotext there are a number of contemporary terms which replaced each other over time, generally denoting the type of establishment. Рюмочная is one explicitly for drinking, before revolution or in soviet time, the term came in use aroung Ivan Vasielvich the Third. After 1990s? We have pubs and bars and whatever you may know. No general pet name for these, unless the name of concrete place can produce one.
The following is true for translating any language: to be able to tanslate correctly you have to read alot and listen a lot of material for the language you're not native to. You need to know memes, phrases, cultural references, or to be able to find them. Unless you're not translating a technical text, you have to translate the context, mood and ideas, not words. For technical translation, thre are formal rules, akin "this phrase must be translated as..."
That's why an LLM translation is immediately obvious and usually a BS one.
*) nadmozg (надмозг) - direct translation of English noun "overmind"**. It was introduced in pirate translation of Starcraft I game and became a term for  bad translators. Or for people who conceive some convoluted schemes.
**) Sometimes bad translations create memes on their own. Very well known one is all your base are belong to us.

My thought process was actually different than making a connection to the English „water hole“. I knew the word пойло, with its spectrum of usage, and therefrom relevant to my thought process: 1) derogatory for low quality beverage, 2) liquid nourishment for livestock. And I knew поилка as any sort of liquid dispenser for animals. From these two I thought it might sound natural to use поилка as in my question – even though I couldn‘t find any examples in the Russian National Corpus for such a usage :)

@Truubehüeter пойло is analog of something between English booze and metaphoric "sauce" (e.g. "lay off the sauce") or "poison" when used as (1), it can be used jokingly about any quality of booze. I really liked variant поильня, a related word to поилка, as an informal variant. It's understandable, if unusual. Some eccentric character may use that jokingly. Its standard usage is informal designation of place where cattle is given water. But in general we just use the establishment's type or have a pet name for particular place or chain.
